# CSS flex box layout breaking

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get this layout working, but it seems to have issues when you scale the window smaller vertically. I need the sidebar panels to have static-height headers and footers, and I need to be able to add 1-3 panels to the left or right sidebar and have them take up the entire space vertically without braking out of their containers. This is proving to be very difficult.

any tips are appreciated!

here is the issue, when you scale the window smaller or larger the panels (grey+white boxes) dont take up the full space, or take up too much.
[image]
[image]

http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/emqgwo?editors=110

```
.panel{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  //padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;

}

header {
  height: 32px; //must be 32px
  background: #c0c0c0;
}

footer{
  background: #cfcfcf;
  height: 32px; //must be 32px
}

.select-list {
  //flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height:16vh;
}

.select-list-item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 32px; //must be 32px
}

//===============================================

body  {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.layout-middle{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.layout-stage{
  flex: 1 0 320px;
  background: #ffc94e;

}

.layout-left, .layout-right{
  flex: 0 0 320px;
  background: #c9ea5d;
}

.layout-left{
  background: #85d6e4;
}

.layout-header{
  height: 100px; //must be 100px
  background: #92e4c9;
}

.layout-footer{
  height: 150px;//must be 150px
  background: #f7846a;
}
```

Comment: use bootstrap it will simplify you design

Comment: Use  percentages. Remember that they are relative to their parent Element.

Comment: can you edit the codepen and show me an example of what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Just use flex also in it

Add:

```
.layout-left{
    flex-direction: column;
}

.panel{
    flex: 1 1 33%;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXPdQz)